# Android list view scroll down lagging

Tags: android

I am using image lazy loader to display a list of custom items (where each row having image and text)
However my list view lags on scroll down.
How can i implement a list view with no scroll lag, just like the app listing list view in play store. Following is the list view xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/list_row_bg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Title Post 1"
            android:textColor="@color/list_title"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_posted_by"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
            android:text="Posted by Paul Curtin 4 days ago on sep05 2013" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_comments_image_margin"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview_comments_count"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_posted_by"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_comments" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_comments_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_posted_by"
            android:padding="@dimen/list_category_padding"
            android:text="comments_count"
            android:textColor="@color/list_category"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_comments_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_thumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_posted_by"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image_small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_thumb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_posted_by"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your Adaptor Class

Comment: Please post your Adapter implementation, I guess you are doing lots of stuff there and not reusing views efficiently.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_ConvertView

Comment: But when i remove the image loader statement from the getview() method of adapter, the lagging disappears

Comment: have you used holder pattern?

Comment: Please post your Adapter class, problem is in that class. Not the layout

Comment: No I meant the listview xml not the internal layout, however set the height to wrap_content. Also you can use a Tag holder or simple holder pattern.

Comment: @AabidMulani Adapter class is some what clumsy, but i think the problem lies in the image loading in background,when the images are removed from layout it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Set this attribute of listview and try

```
android:scrollbars="none"


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMyAlbum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem lies in the image loader:
 Try different image loaders

1] Universal Image Loader [Here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

2] Lazy List Loader [Here](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

3] Volley Image Loader [Here](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/)

Comment: did any of these overcome the lagging part?